# make input in focus in angular 2/5

Tags: angular, angular5

Input element will be shown after the click (OnViewInit it's hidden).
I need this Input will be in focus when it appears. It works fine when input is NOT hidden by *ngIf ( #inputElement2 ).

Is it possible to implement it for #inputElement1 ?

HTML:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="isVisible">
  <input #inputElement1 placeholder="input element 1"/>
</div>


<input #inputElement2 placeholder="input element 2"/>

<div>
  <button (click)="toggleInput();">focus</button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  isVisible = false ;
  @ViewChild("inputElement1") inputEl: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("inputElement2") inputEl2: ElementRef;

  toggleInput() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
    if(this.inputEl){
      this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus();
    }
    this.inputEl2.nativeElement.focus()
  }
```

Comment: you can use auto focus attribute to focus the element

Comment: Try keeping the code in setTimeout like shown below

Comment: @ChellappanV - surprisingly autofocus attribute working just once after first button click. on the second click it stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
toggleInput() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
   setTimeout(()=> {
            if(this.inputEl){
              this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus();
            }
            this.inputEl2.nativeElement.focus();
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Nandita Arora Sharma, it's working for me. Could you explain why? What setTimeout() doing ?

Comment: It executes this block after the current changeDetectionCycle. Upto that time, the ngIf would have the true value and DOM will have that element in it. And hence your code would work. read this for more info https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **when** you call the focus event. Because you are using `nativeElement` (an unsafe and unreliable way) the code doesn't work as expected.

To make it work like this you can change it to something like:

```
  toggleInput() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.isVisible) {
      this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus();
    } else {
      this.inputEl2.nativeElement.focus()
    }
  }
```

You will have to implement `AfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook, i.e.

```
export class MypComponent implements AfterViewChecked
```